# Extjs Namespaces and TabReorderer

Tags: google-chrome, extjs, namespaces, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to use the Ext.ux.TabReorderer plugin provided in the "ux" folder, but am having trouble getting it to work in a namespace.

When I do it normally (without a namespace defined), it works just fine. (Like below.)

```
var tabPanel = Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel', {
renderTo: Ext.Element.get('tabs1'),
        bodyStyle: 'padding: 5px',
        plugins: Ext.create('Ext.ux.TabReorderer'),
        items: [{
            xtype: 'panel',
            title: 'Tab 1',
            html : 'Test 1',
            closable: true
        }, {
            xtype: 'panel',
            title: 'Tab 2',
            html : 'Test 2',
            closable: true
        },{
            xtype: 'panel',
            title: 'Tab 3',
            html : 'Test 3',
            closable: true
        },{
            xtype: 'panel',
            title: 'Tab 4',
            html : 'Test 4',
            closable: true
        }]
    });
```

But when I put it in a namespace it does not work.

```
Ext.define('MyApp.Layout.CenterTabs', {        extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
        bodyStyle: 'padding: 5px',
        plugins: Ext.create('Ext.ux.TabReorderer'),
        items: [{
            xtype: 'panel',
            title: 'Tab 1',
            html : 'Test 1',
            closable: true
        }, {
            xtype: 'panel',
            title: 'Tab 2',
            html : 'Test 2',
            closable: true
        },{
            xtype: 'panel',
            title: 'Tab 3',
            html : 'Test 3',
            closable: true
        },{
            xtype: 'panel',
            title: 'Tab 4',
            html : 'Test 4',
            closable: true
        }]
    });
```

In Chrome I get the error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load [OMMITTED THIS
>   PART]/extjs-4.1.0/examples/ux/TabReorderer.js?_dc=1338489585629. Cross
>   origin requests are only supported for HTTP.

Why is this and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

First off the error you are seeing does not have to do with the code you are using.  It looks like some kind of script error not using a webserver maybe, I have no clue.

That being said you are using Ext.define wrong http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext-method-define.  What you are doing in your example is putting shared objects on the prototype which generally should not be done.

Instead you are want to something like :

```
Ext.define('MyApp.Layout.CenterTabs', {
    extend : 'Ext.tab.Panel',
    //Strings can be put on the prototype and is good practice too
    //because it allows for easy configing  
    bodyStyle : 'padding: 5px',
    initComponent : function() {
        Ext.apply(this, {
            plugins : Ext.create('Ext.ux.TabReorderer'),
            items : [{
                xtype : 'panel',
                title : 'Tab 1',
                html : 'Test 1',
                closable : true
            }, {
                xtype : 'panel',
                title : 'Tab 2',
                html : 'Test 2',
                closable : true
            }, {
                xtype : 'panel',
                title : 'Tab 3',
                html : 'Test 3',
                closable : true
            }, {
                xtype : 'panel',
                title : 'Tab 4',
                html : 'Test 4',
                closable : true
            }]
        })

        this.callParent()
    }
});

var tabPanel1 = Ext.create('MyApp.Layout.CenterTabs', { renderTo: Ext.Element.get('tabs1') }),
    tabPanel2 = Ext.create('MyApp.Layout.CenterTabs', { renderTo: Ext.Element.get('tabs2') })
//Now the plugin instances will not be shared between the two variables.
```